# How can I improve this Matlab code usability

Tags: image, matlab

I'm writing a code that read 12 rgb images (the images are colored circles on a black background) and it makes some calculation on them to calculate the spot size of the circle. I'll show an examples of the calculation that makes:

```
% read images
image_1=readNPY('image_1.npy');
image_2=readNPY('image_2.npy');
...
image_12=readNPY('image_12.npy');

% change from type uint16 to double and calculate the maximum
image1=double(image_1);
image1MAX=max(max(image1));
...
image12=double(image_12);
image12MAX=max(max(image12));

% normalizes to the maximum
reference = exp(-1)
IMAGE1=fix(image1./image1MAX/reference);
...
IMAGE12=fix(image12./image12MAX/reference);

% calculate the spot size
spot_image1 = 2*sqrt(size(nonzeros(IMAGE1),1)/pi)/1000;
...
spot_image12 = 2*sqrt(size(nonzeros(IMAGE12),1)/pi)/1000;

% plot the spot size
spot = [spot_image1 spot_image2 ... spot_image12]
xvalue = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
plot(xvalue, spot)
```

The code works well, my question is:
if i have 52 images instead of 12 images, do I have to add 40 lines for each calculation or there is a smarter way to implement it?
(I hope you understand my doubts, thank you!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your image file names are in the format:

'*image_1.npy*', '*image_2.npy*', ... '*image_10.npy*', '*image_11.npy*'...

**Option 1 - using cell and numeric arrays:** You can generate the file names in a cell array and read them in a loop, using cell and numeric arrays to calculate the data for each image:

```
% Number of image files
mumImages = 112;

% Generate image file names with desired format
imageNames = compose('image_%d.npy', 1:mumImages);

% Initialize cell arrays and numeric arrays (recommended, not required)
image_ = cell(size(imageNames));
image = cell(size(imageNames));
imageMAX = cell(size(imageNames));
IMAGE = cell(size(imageNames));
spot = zeros(size(imageNames));

% Populate the cell arrays and numeric arrays
for i = 1:mumImages
    image_{i} = readNPY(imageNames{i});
    image{i} = double(image_{i});
    imageMAX{i} = max(max(image{i}));

    % normalizes to the maximum
    reference = exp(-1);
    IMAGE{i} = fix(image{i}./imageMAX{i}/reference);

    % calculate the spot size
    spot(i) = 2*sqrt(size(nonzeros(IMAGE{i}),1)/pi)/1000;

end

% plot the spot size
plot(1:mumImages, spot)
```

**Option 2 - using a stuct array:** You can do the same as above with a stuct array

```
% Number of image files
mumImages = 112;

% Genrate image file names with desired format
imageNames = compose('image_%d.npy', 1:mumImages);

% Initialize a struct with desired fields (recommended, not required)
C = repmat(struct('image_',[], 'image', [], 'imageMAX', [], 'IMAGE', [], 'spot', []), mumImages, 1 );

% Populate the struct array fields
for i = 1:mumImages
    C(i).image_ = readNPY(imageNames{i});
    C(i).image = double(C(i).image_);
    C(i).imageMAX = max(max(C(i).image));

    % normalizes to the maximum
    reference = exp(-1);
    C(i).IMAGE = fix(C(i).image./C(i).imageMAX/reference);

    % calculate the spot size
    C(i).spot = 2*sqrt(size(nonzeros(C(i).IMAGE),1)/pi)/1000;

end

% plot the spot size
plot(1:mumImages, [C.spot])
```